# How to iterate through array combinations with constant sum efficiently?

Tags: algorithm

I have an array and its length is `X`. Each element of the array has range `1 .. L`. I want to iterate efficiently through all array combinations that has sum `L`.

Correct solutions for: L = 4 and X = 2

```
1 3
3 1
2 2
```

Correct solutions for: L = 5 and X = 3

```
1 1 3
1 3 1
3 1 1
1 2 2
2 1 2
2 2 1
```

The naive implementation is (no wonder) too slow for my problem (X is up to 8 in my case and L is up to 128).

Could anybody tell me how is this problem called or where to find a fast algorithm for the problem?

Thanks!

Comment: It looks to me as if you are looking for the *integer partitions* of `L` of length `X`.

Comment: You cannot do it *efficiently* (in the literature, efficiently=polynomially). There are exponential number of solutions, and to iterate all of them requires exponential time.

Comment: This would be a great project euler problem =)

Comment: I find your examples confusing, because you haven't provided the input array.  Or is that when you say "each element has range 1 .. L" you actually mean "element i is equal to i"? (In which case why mention arrays at all?)

Answer (score 9):

If I understand correctly, you're given two numbers 1 ≤ *X* ≤ *L* and you want to generate all sequences of positive integers of length *X* that sum to *L*.

(Note: this is similar to the [integer partition problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_%28number_theory%29), but not the same, because you consider 1,2,2 to be a different sequence from 2,1,2, whereas in the integer partition problem we ignore the order, so that these are considered to be the same partition.)

The sequences that you are looking for correspond to the [combinations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination) of *X* − 1 items out of *L* − 1. For, if we put the numbers 1 to *L* − 1 in order, and pick *X* − 1 of them, then the lengths of intervals between the chosen numbers are positive integers that sum to *L*.

For example, suppose that *L* is 16 and *X* is 5. Then choose 4 numbers from 1 to 15 inclusive:

[image: the four numbers 3, 7, 8, and 14 are chosen from 1 to 15]

Add 0 at the beginning and 16 at the end, and the intervals are:

[image: intervals 0–3, 3–7, 7–8, 8–14 and 14–16]

and 3 + 4 + 1 + 6 + 2 = 16 as required.

So [generate the combinations](https://stackoverflow.com/a/127856/68063) of *X* − 1 items out of *L* − 1, and for each one, convert it to a partition by finding the intervals. For example, in Python you could write:

```py
from itertools import combinations

def partitions(n, t):
    """
    Generate the sequences of `n` positive integers that sum to `t`.
    """
    assert(1 <= n <= t)
    def intervals(c):
        last = 0
        for i in c:
            yield i - last
            last = i
        yield t - last
    for c in combinations(range(1, t), n - 1):
        yield tuple(intervals(c))

>>> list(partitions(2, 4))
[(1, 3), (2, 2), (3, 1)]
>>> list(partitions(3, 5))
[(1, 1, 3), (1, 2, 2), (1, 3, 1), (2, 1, 2), (2, 2, 1), (3, 1, 1)]
```

There are (*L* − 1)! / (*X* − 1)!(*L* − *X*)! combinations of *X* − 1 items out of *L* − 1, so the runtime of this algorithm (and the size of its output) is exponential in *L*.  However, if you don't count the output, it only needs O(*L*) space.

With *L* = 128 and *X* = 8, there are 89,356,415,775 partitions, so it'll take a while to output them all!

(Maybe if you explain why you are computing these partitions, we might be able to suggest some way of meeting your requirements without having to actually produce them all.)

Comment: I think this implementation could be optimized slightly if you move `intervals` out of the loop and pass `c` as an input parameter -- That way you aren't creating a new function for each combination.

Comment: @mgilson: I moved the function definition out of the loop to make you happy. But this kind of optimization seems kind of futile in the face of the program's exponential runtime behaviour. It would be better to figure out how to avoid computing these partitions at all.

Comment: I agree -- It's a super minor optimization in the face of the nearly hopeless task.  But if we're going to write an implementation for this, it might as well be a good one :-)

Comment: How would you expand this to add zero-partitions if n>t?