# How to iterate over a range of permutations?

Tags: python

Say you have `n` items each ranging from 1-100. How can I get go over all possible variations within the range?

Example:

```
3 stocks A, B and C
```

Working to find possible portfolio allocation.

```
A - 0     0   0            1    2          1    1
B - 0     1   2      ...   0    0    ...   1    2
C - 100   99  98           99   98         98   97
```

Looking for an **efficient** way to get a matrix of all possible outcomes.

Sum should add up to 100 and cover all possible variations for `n` elements.

Comment: This is a pretty unclear question... Are you saying that you want all permutations of three numbers between 1 and 100 such that the sum of the three equals 100?

Comment: @mgilson Yes, that is correct. I'll update question. Looking for an efficient way to handle it though. And for `n` numbers, obviously

Comment: [3SUM problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3SUM) in non-zero sum variant?

Comment: This sounds like you're trying to brute-force a problem that would be better solved by getting a more sophisticated library for it.

Comment: Maybe use numpy for the matrix presentation? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17870612/printing-a-two-dimensional-array-in-python

Comment: I think your problem has an answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13988197/how-to-iterate-through-array-combinations-with-constant-sum-efficiently.

Answer (score 2):

How I'd do it:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> cp = itertools.product(range(101),repeat=3)
>>> portfolios = list(p for p in cp if sum(p)==100)
```

But that creates unnecessary combinations.  See discussions of integer partitioning to avoid that.  E.g., [Elegant Python code for Integer Partitioning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10035752/elegant-python-code-for-integer-partitioning)

Comment: This is O(N^3) -- It'll take a million iterations when you should be able to come up with a solution in about 5000 iterations (for N = 100).

Comment: The amount-of-used-code-lines efficiency is great.

Comment: @mgilson Agreed.  That's why I provided the link for integer partitioning.